# reading sql file and writing to csv file

Tags: c#, csv

I have created a program for the user to access a database, then choose a company and run 5 different sql queries for that company to create csv files for each of them.

The problem is in one of my csv files some of the data is not displaying in the right columns.

```
private void btnEmployees_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string employees = File.ReadAllText("X:/ZoddsandEnds/Emer/SQL/Employees.txt");
    string accessConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source =" + dataAddress + ";Persist Security Info=False;";
    string accessSelectEmployee = employees;
    OleDbConnection accessConnection = null;

    try
    {
        accessConnection = new OleDbConnection(accessConnect);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("An error has occurred, failed to connect to the database.\r\n" + ex);
    }

    try
    {
        OleDbCommand accessCommand = new OleDbCommand(accessSelectEmployee, accessConnection);
        OleDbDataAdapter accessDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(accessCommand);

        accessConnection.Open();
        accessDataAdapter.Fill(accessDataSet, "employee");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("An error has occurred, failed to retrieve data from the database.\r\n" + ex);
        return;
    }
    finally
    {
        accessConnection.Close();
    }

    string csvFileName = dataAddress.Replace(".mcp", "Employee.csv");

    using (StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(csvFileName))
    {
        sWriter.WriteLine("Reference, Gender, Title, Forename, Surname, Address1, Address2, Address3, Address4, Postcode, Country, Marital Status, Birth Date, Employment Status, Start Date, Leave Date," +
                        "Leaver, P45_1_IF_Required, Directorship Start Date, Branch, Cost Centre, Department, Run Group, Default Cost Split, NI Number, NI Letter, Tax Code, Week1/Month1, Tax Code Change Type," +
                        "Frequency, Payment Method, Bank Account No, Bank Account Name, Sort Code, Bank Name, Bank Branch, Building Society Ref, Autopay Ref, Taxable Pay Previous Employment, Taxable Pay This Employment," +
                        "Tax Previous Employment, Tax This Employment, NetPay To Date, Directors Earnings To Date, BF NI Letter, BF NI Calculation Basis, BF Earnings To LEL, BF Earnings To SET," +
                        "BF Earnings to PET, BF Earnings To UAP, BF Earnings To UEL, BF Earnings Above UEL, BF Ee Contributions Pt1, BF Ee Contributions Pt2, BF Er Contributions, BF Ee Rebate, BF Er Rebate, BF Ee Reduction," +
                        "StudentLoanFromDate, StudentLoanToDate, StudentLoanDeducted, Email, EeNIPdByErTD, ExPatExempt, DateOfArrival, TaxExemptPcnt,TaxExemptIncomeTD, TaxExemptGUIncomeTD, EeGuOverride, CalcEeGrossToNetFirst, NoNIGU, GrossUpPensionContribs, GUStudentLoan," +
                        "Double tax agreement, Foreign tax credit, UK Tax YTD, Foreign Tax YTD, TransferDate, Standard Hours, Worker Subject to Postponement Period, Postponement End Date, Postponement period Part Periods Allowed, Jobholder Opt In Notice Received," +
                        "Entitled Worker Active Membership Start, Passport Number, Starting Declaration, Irregular Emloyement, Omit From RTI, Payment to a Non Individal,Old RTI Ee Reference, P45(3) Tax Office Number, P45(3) Tax Office Reference, P45(3) Leave Date, P45(3) Tax Code, P45(3) Week 1 Month 1, P45(3) Tax Period- Monthly/Weekly, P45(3) Tax Period - Period Number, P45(3) Previous Tax Year," +
                        "P45(3) Previous Pay, P45(3) Previous Tax, P45(3)Student Loan, P46 Statement A,B or C, P46 Student Loans (Box D), P46 (pen) Tax Office Number, P46 (Pen) Tax Office Reference, P46 (Pen) Leave Date, P46(Pen) Tax Code, P46(Pen) Week 1 Month 1," +
                        " P46(Pen) Tax Period - Monthly/Weekly, P46(Pen) Tax Period - Period Number, P46(Pen) Previous Tax Year, P46(Pen) previous Pay, P46(Pen) Previous Tax, P46 (Pen) Annual Pension, P46(Pen) Is Recently Bereaved, P46(Expat) Statement A, B or C" +
                        "P46 (Expat Student Loan Indicator, P46 (Expat) EEA or Commonwealth Citizen, P46 (Expat) EPM6 Scheme,");

        DataRowCollection accessDRC = accessDataSet.Tables["employee"].Rows;
        int colCount = accessDataSet.Tables["employee"].Columns.Count;

        foreach (DataRow accessDR in accessDRC)
        {
            string csvline = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++)
            {
                csvline = csvline + accessDR[i] + ",";
            }
            sWriter.WriteLine(csvline);
        }
        accessDataSet.Tables["employee"].Clear();
    }
}
```

Here is an example of the way the csv file shows the data:

![Here is an example of the way the csv file shows the data][1]

Comment: CSV is actually more complicated than "just add commas"... have you handled values with commas in? carriage returns? etc?

Comment: That's a very bad way of building a string, btw

Comment: The first thing you should do here is: look at exactly what the file contains, especially for the problem lines. Looking at it in Excel (or whatever tool that is) is not helpful. Can you show the raw text output?

Comment: what do you mean carriage returns?

Comment: Plus, the first `try/catch` is quite useless, unless you provide a string like `trollface` to the constructor of the `OleDbConnection`, that you need to catch.

Comment: @user3734454 any combination of characters with value 10 or 13; data in the source table can contain these characters, especially if people know the shift+enter trick. Likewise, data in the source table can contain commas. Such values need special handling - quoting (remembering to escape the quotes), etc

Comment: I looked at it on a text file Commas are the only thing splitting the text though there is sometimes more than one comma used

Comment: @user3734454 could you show some sample rows of the text format of that? Ideally for the rows you already displayed in a table format? I can imagine that multiple commas in this case are not really the issue, for instance for the first row I would expect something like `SE145JN,,U....` so there are two consecutive commas, because there is no (or an empty one) value between SE145JN and U

Comment: ,,GU15 3TD,,U,29/12/1991,E,27/05/2014,,N,   that is how it is displayed on the text file

Comment: on a side note: I am pretty sure you can avoid your inner `for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++)`-loop altogether if you replace it with just `csvline = string.Join(",", accessDR)`, that way you wont have extra commas at the end of every line also

Comment: @DrCopyPaste When you do that no data comes into the csv file at all

Comment: @user3734454 ah sry my bad, just tried it out myself it should have been `csvline = string.Join(",", accessDR.ItemArray)` of course ;)

Comment: The best advice I can give you is to not use CSV as a data format. If it's going to be looked at by users, then build an Excel (.xlsx) file. If it's going to be passed to other programs, then use formats with good serialization support, such as JSON or XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Marc Gravell said, likely your data has an extra comma in it for those rows... it looks like you're viewing the results in Excel, have you looked at the raw csv file just as a text file? That should show you why those lines look different. You have to be careful simply copying data without handling for commas, newline chars, etc. in the database. Ask me how I know ;)

You can add double quotes around each string for Excel to interpret them as text and ignore the commas inside the string like this:

```
csvline = csvline + "\"" + accessDR[i] + "\"" + ",";
```

Comment: yes I looked at it in a text file and some of the data does contain more than one comma but how do I split that up then?

Comment: @user3734454 are you restricted to only using comma as a seperator? csv can come in many different "flavors", `;` and `TAB` are also pretty common as delimiters...

Comment: @DrCopyPaste `,,GU15 3TD,,U,29/12/1991,E,27/05/2014,,N,` that is how it is displayed on the text file –

Comment: That's what I usually do if I'm in a hurry; I like the pipe "|" delimiter because it's found less frequently in text. Edited the answer to show how to handle comma inside a string for excel.